# Azure bot app doesn't updating after modifications

Tags: node.js, azure, bots, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I created a bot in Azure to integrate with Microsoft Teams in node.js, but when I change the file index.js, changes are not reflected when I test my bot in test tab. I tried to restart the app, build.cmd doesn't work (apparently for C# only) and followed instructions here, but it doesn't seems to work

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-build-online-code-editor?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

Any ideas to get the updated code to work?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `Restart` in `All App service settings`?

Answer (score 0):

Click the 'Run' button on the left pane of the online code editor. See example circled in red [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEmtl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you created the bot with the Bot Service --which is basically a Functions-based bot, you will need to compile the webpack file (called here funcpack) after any modification.

This can be done from the Azure console (https://THE-NAME-OF-YOUR-BOT-HERE.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole) on the wwwroot folder, invoking the following command:

```
funcpack pack ./
```

For more information take a look at [this post](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-pack) 
Let me know if it works for you. Cheers! :)